# R language in Anaconda3: The packages is alrerady installed and in libpath folder. but it can not included

Tags: r, path, anaconda

I am new in R language. Today I have install a package and it is successful.and I have checked the .libPaths() folder and the package is there. but it always show the error 'here is no package called 'backports''
although the package "backports" already in the folder

```
library(backports, lib.loc='C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/Renv/Lib/R/library')
```

> Error in library(backports, lib.loc = "C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/Renv/Lib/R/library"): there is no package called 'backports'
>   Traceback:
>   1. library(backports, lib.loc = "C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/Renv/Lib/R/library")

Comment: maybe tag your question with `anaconda`, since this seems to be an anaconda problem rather than an R problem. Especially on Windows where binary package installation is the norm, I don't see a real advantage to using anaconda.

Comment: thanks for your helping.@Martin Morgan

Answer (score 0):

I have solved. It is the problem of Anaconda. There are many another r- version in conda-forge.  Instead of using

```
conda install <package>
```

using

```
conda install -c conda-forge <package>
```